# Nested try/catch inside block and PMD rule

Tags: java, try-catch, refactoring, pmd

I'm trying to refactor this code cause PMD throwing Failure:PreserveStackTrace:3, the main problem is how I can collapse exception e1 into e2, is it anti-pattern right now?
I thinking about extract second try or put it into finally but it might cause problems with bussiness logic.

Code:

```
        try {
            try {
                response = paypal.execute(params);
            } catch (final FailedConnectionAttempException e1) {
                log.warn("The first attempt is failed " + " Tryin again ", e1);

                try {
                    response = paypal.execute(params);
                } catch (final FailedConnectionAttempException e2) {
                    throw new PaymentException("The second attempt failed ", e2);
                }
            }
        } catch (final IntegrationException e) {
            throw new PaymentException("Unable to execute ", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using apache HttpClient?

Comment: No, it it not httpClient definition of Response is my own class.

Comment: A) consider to only use `final` where it really improves your code, as in: it doesn't add any value in your catch blocks B) The answer sounds good, if that doesn't work for you ... you could put the whole thing in a `while retryCounter > 0` loop. `return` when there is no exception, count down `retryCounter` in the catch block. Then you don't have any need for "nested" try/catch.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, i will try it

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using the Apache HttpClient because I recognize the execute method.

You can use the HttpRequestRetryHandler to configure retry behavior instead of handling with that catch block.

```
HttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler = new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {
    @Override
    public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {
        return executionCount < 5;
    }
};
```

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setRetryHandler(retryHandler)
        .build();
```

Also I should also mention, HttpClient will retry a failed request 3 times **by default** and I notice in your exceptions it says first/second attempt, in reality it is the first 4 attempts and the first 7 attempts, so you can consider how many retries you really need.

Comment: No, it it not httpClient definition of Response is my own class

Comment: what is paypal.execute() doing? Also I would strongly consider using some sort of library to handle Http requests, it's something you will probably reuse often and get so much more functionality out of the box.

Comment: It is sending request with given params to auth payment

Comment: For now i would like to focus only on this specific fragment of code, not at API

Comment: In that case I would second what @GhostCat recommended and suggest wrapping it in a retry while loop